# More Precise Floating point Data Types than double?

Tags: c++, types

In my project I have to compute division, multiplication, subtraction, addition on a matrix of `double` elements.
The problem is that when the size of matrix increases the accuracy of my output is drastically getting affected.
Currently I am using `double` for each element which I believe uses `8 bytes` of memory & has accuracy of `16 digits` irrespective of decimal position.
Even for large size of matrix the memory occupied by all the elements is in the range of few kilobytes. So I can afford to use `datatypes` which require more memory.
So I wanted to know which data type is more precise than `double`.
I tried searching in some books & I could find `long double`.
But I dont know what is its precision.
And what if I want more precision than that?

Comment: Check out the GMP project.  Also there are methods to minimize round off error in computations.

Comment: In case you could rely on external dependencies, Boost 1.53 has a Multiprecision library that can helps you!!

Comment: If you're doing this for coursework, they're probably trying to teach you about ordering operations to reduce precision errors.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I think decimal64 correponds to double, then does decimal128 correspond to long double?
Because I believe I need to use decimal 128.

Comment: Using a little algebra to rearrange mathematical calculations can help to reduce rounding errors

Comment: @PeterWood no I this is not a homework. This is my personal project!

Comment: @EdHeal can you please elaborate a bit on what you are saying?

Comment: Switching to a larger type merely delays the numerical collapse. To avoid it completely, crack out a numerical analysis book and read the chapter on "stability".

Comment: @RaymondChen can you please tell me what you mean by "numerical collapse".
I am not a CS student, rather mechanical, so dont understand what you are saying. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Cool_Coder Decimal arithmetic is a bit exotic, used mainly by mainframes for accounting. The common types in C and C++ are binary.

Comment: even double?
Now I am confused!
I just want a data type which gives me more precision in storing decimal values.
What do you recommend?

Comment: Numerical collapse is the phenomenon you're experiencing: Rounding errors accumulate and lead to a wrong answer.

Comment: @Cool_Coder - There are a large number of text books on this subject. Take for instance that adding two numbers with very different exponents requires one of them to have the mantissa to be shifted to enable the addition to occur. With some complex calculations you may be able to do some mathematical operations in a different order to avoid this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, 80-bit "Intel" IEEE 754 [extended-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) `long double`, which is 80 bits padded to 16 bytes in memory, has 64 bits mantissa, with no implicit bit, which gets you 19.26 decimal digits. This has been the almost universal standard for `long double` for ages, but recently things have started to change.

The newer 128-bit [quad-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_precision_floating-point_format) format has 112 mantissa bits plus an implicit bit, which gets you 34 decimal digits. GCC implements this as the `__float128` type and there is (if memory serves) a compiler option to set `long double` to it.

Comment: so who would you recommend between long double & __float128, considering the tradeoff involved in speed & accuracy?

Comment: @Cool_Coder I don't know the characteristics of your program, but since it's easy, just try both!

Comment: ok I will & let you know. Just for the sake of it let me know if the following is incorrect:


__float128 *nicePrecision = new __float128();

Comment: 128-bit floats aren't all that new. They're the `long double` type on SPARC, which has been around for ages (as in, a little more than twenty years).

Comment: @PeteBecker That's still a lot newer than the 8087! And the standardization only came about in 2008, unless I'm mistaken. Anyway my impression is that they're gaining traction now because the legacy 80-bit hardware is mostly gone.

Comment: @Cool_Coder Unfortunately I've never actually used `__float128`, and I don't know what version of GCC it requires. I use the bleeding edge latest anyway.

Comment: @Potatoswatter according to info on this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/
long double & double have same precision?

Comment: @Cool_Coder cplusplus.com is a very poor resource. Its editors put little effort into anything besides SEO, which is why Google always puts it on the first page. Better to ask here. For what it's worth, they *may* be the same type, but they're usually not. [`std::numeric_limits< long double >`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is a `struct` with all the info you could want about its properties.

Comment: Which C type maps to which IEEE type is usually defined by the operating system, by the way. Then the OS spec (ABI) may leave wiggle room for compiler options. It appears that MS has recommended that they be the same. Their platform is less popular for numeric and scientific computing.

Comment: Just something to be mindful of: as of this moment GCC optimizes `double` into MMX and `long double` into FPU instructions. There will be a performance hit.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to consider the sequence of operations, i.e. do the additions in an ordered sequence starting with the smallest values first. This will increase overall accuracy of the results using the same precision in the mantissa:

```
1e00 + 1e-16 + ... + 1e-16 (1e16 times) = 1e00
1e-16 + ... + 1e-16 (1e16 times) + 1e00 = 2e00
```

The point is that adding small numbers to a large number will make them disappear. So the latter approach reduces the numerical error

Answer (score 3):

Floating point data types with greater precision than `double` are going to depend on your compiler and architecture.

In order to get more than `double` precision, you may need to rely on some math library that supports arbitrary precision calculations.  These probably won't be fast though.

Comment: "These probably won't be fast enough" <- Fast enough for what? What makes you say that? And what alternatives do you suggest if one does need more precision?!

Comment: You sort of seem to be ignoring the existence of `long double`. The same issues do sort of apply, but to a much lesser extent.

Comment: @us2012 I just said probably won't be fast, not not fast enough.  So yes, it depends a lot on what the OP is trying to do.  I'd suggest a math library if I knew one, but my experience with arbitrary precision like this is limited to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

On Intel architectures the precision of `long double` is [80bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format).

What kind of values do you want to represent? Maybe you are better off using fixed precision.

Comment: `long float`? Really? 80 bits precision and how many go into the exponent?

Comment: Depends on the compiler; with MS, a `long double` has the same precision as a `double`.

Comment: I meant long double, it was just a glitch.