# A more accurate data type than float or double? C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, decimal

Does C++ have a more accurate data type than float or double, or do I just have to settle for the fact that my calculations will be off?

EDIT:  As Mr. Lister has pointed out, my question is regarding the precision.  It's a bit frustrating when you add two floats/doubles together and the number is off half the time comparing to the calculation done by hand.

Comment: Is `long double` available in C++? Apart from that, use a numeric library like MPFR.

Comment: Define "more accurate data type"

Comment: @P0W One that can hold more decimal places than `double`.

Comment: Check out this:- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_precision_floating-point_format

Comment: boost::multiprecision

Comment: your calculations will always be "off" using a computer unless you use some sort of esoteric math library that keeps track of irrational numbers, how accurate do you need things to be

Comment: GMP : -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library

Comment: Does 0.00000000001 really matter?

Comment: @Doorknob Given that `double` can store numbers with over 300 zeros behind the decimal point, I'd say it matters, otherwise they woulnd't have bothered.

Comment: Anyway, you all assume the OP means more digits, but couldn't it be possible that he just means more precise handling of decimal numbers?

Comment: @H2CO3 As double doesn't really have a defined number of decimal places, that's not really a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You could also take a look at this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659668/more-precise-floating-point-data-types-than-double

Comment: @EJP You tell me a platform please which doesn't use IEEE-754 as fp?

Comment: It really depends what kind of computations you want to do. As pointed out by @aaronman, no library will represent irrational numbers exactly. If you need to represent hundredth exactly, e.g. for monetary amounts, no binary floating-point system, at any precision, will be satisfactory. Where do the quantities you wish to represent come from and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: No *numerical* library will represent irrational numbers exactly. Symbolic mathematical software can.

Comment: Mr. Lister is on the right track here.  I am looking at more precise handling.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't know why you're asking me. I didn't say there were any such platforms. If you are implying that IEEE-754 implies a fixed number of decimal places you are sadly mistaken. It implies a maximum number of decimal *digits*. Not the same thing.

Comment: If you're worried about loosing precision when you add numbers together you need to pay more attention to the magnitude of the values that you're adding. Summing values with vastly different exponents will likely cause the contribution smaller value to be truncated. That's the nature of floating point. Try to structure your computations so this doesn't happen. On technique is to store your high-magnitude fix-point separately from a high-precision difference term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some compilers, and on some architectures, "long double" will give give you more precision than double. If you are on an x86 platform the x87 FPU has an "extended" 80-bit floating point format. Gcc and Borland compilers give you an 80 bit float value when you use the "long double" type. Note that [Visual Studio does not support this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/9cx8xs15.aspx) (the maximum supported by MSVC is double precision, 64 bit).

There is something called a "[double double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-double_arithmetic#Double-double_arithmetic)" which is a software technique for implementing quad-precision 128-bit floating point. You can find libraries that implement it.

You could also investigate libraries for [arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

For some calculations a 64 bit integer is a better choice than a 64 bit floating point value.

But if your question is about built-in types in current C++ compilers on common platforms then the answer is that you're limited to double (64 bit floating point), and on 64 bit platforms you have 64 bit ints. If you can stick to x86 and use the right compiler you can also have long double (80-bit extended precision).

You might be interested in this question:

[long double (GCC specific) and __float128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516476/long-double-gcc-specific-and-float128)